# trying to check if username exists in sqlite database using python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, python-3.x

Trying to check if the username is exists in sqlite using python 3

This is what i've tried

```
    checkUsername = self.c.execute("SELECT username FROM Login WHERE username = ? AND position = ?",
                   (username, manager))

    if checkUsername != 0:
        print("Wrong username and password")
    else:
        print("correct")
```

Comment: which module are you using? What result are you getting from that query (error or something else). Please, update your question with these answers.

Comment: no error just keeps saying wrong username when its the correct one

Comment: As Christopher answered, you will need `checkUsername = self.c.fetchone()` after `self.c.execute`. Also If you need to check using query `SELECT count(1) ...` which will return 1.

Comment: thanks emin its working now

Comment: vote up for comment will help a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the sqlite3 module, cursor.execute doesn't return the results. You need to use cursor.fetchone() or cursor.fetchall() to get the results, which come back as a tuple or list of tuples.

Check the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone) for some more details.

Comment: i know about using cursor.fetchall() i originally did that then used a if statement to check whether the username inputted was in the tuple.